# UK PhD admissions - Does partial industry funding improve my chances?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, united-kingdom, industry

I am in a situation where my employer is willing to put up a significant portion of the cost of a physics PhD in the UK. I have spoken to a supervisor at a top university and we've broadly agreed on a project and he says there will be ways to top up the remaining funds from other sources. He is happy with my grades and research experience as well as my research proposal. He wants me to apply right away and not wait for the usual funded application season later.

I'm wondering whether the fact that I am applying with partial industry funding makes admission easier? I have a gut feeling that the university is above my league but I'm being encouraged to apply by an employer and my would-be supervisor.

TL;DR is it because of my employer funding that I stand a better chance of admission?

Comment: It makes it easier in the sense that partial funds are there to be used, which is better than competing for funds. (You might want to ask your employer to fully fund. You might also want to clarify whether funding covers travel.)

Comment: It makes your application more complicated if your employer wants to retain IP, but your university should be familiar with such cases and it shouldn't cause a problem if your employer accepts the university's terms.

Comment: Isn't admission unrelated to funding in the UK?